# access NodeJS process.env in client side

Tags: node.js

I am solving a challenging ctf problem in which, the flag is in process.env of nodejs server. I can access source code of server ( bcs they public by express.static....) So is there anyway to access process.env of nodejs in client side?

Comment: Not unless either the app is exposing it somehow (eg in the response of some API call) or if you can get into the server via some other exploit.

Comment: sounds like you only have access to client-side source code being served, not the actual source code of the server?

Comment: I can access all sources code of server. I even reconstructed the server on my local. But they store flag in process.env, so I cant reconstructure this variable

Answer (score 1):

There is a misunderstanding. `express.static`, is not giving you access to the server Javascript code. Instead it allows you to use selected code on both the server and the client side.

This allows you to share code on both sides, but it will never allow you to execute code on the client side in the server context.

This means, that you will not be able to execute server specific code on the client side like `process.env`.

You have basically two choices to get access on the client side to that flag :

- you write the flag into the markup of the web page
- you make an ajax request to the server that responds with this information.

Comment: Yes, I do know the express.static just shares sources public data from server to client. So I wonder where server nodejs assigns process.env['flag']? In source code, there is a line "if (win) console.log(process.env.flag)"

Comment: You miss something very basic : the browser is different from node. In the browser you have a window, a document and a navigator object,but they don't exist in node. In node, you have a process and an http object, but you don't have those in the browser.